# how to change iframe src url anchor tags attribute target=_blank on cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have iframe and i want to change target="_blank" or want to remove that attribute  instead of iframe target="_parent".

Anybody have an idea about the script. How can i change or remove the properties from iframe child anchor tag.

when iframe is open on my domain and when i clicked on uploaded website any hyperlink new tab is opened but i want to get new page within the iframe.

I have tried code like that :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


    setTimeout(function(){

    $('#iframeid').contents().find('.linklist_single a').click(function() { 
            $(this).removeAttr('target');
        });
    },2000);

});

</script>
```

OR

Comment: I have tried this as well 


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var href= $("#ebrary").attr("src", 
$(this).attr(".linklist_single a", 
$this.attr("target", "")));
});

</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the DOM of a page in an iframe across origins.

If you have the co-operation of the other site, then you could use [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to send a message asking the other site to change its own DOM. This would require that the function to modify the DOM be on their page and that they have an event listener looking out for your message.

If you can do that, however, it would usually be easier to make the change server side based on a query string.

Comment: Thanks Quentin for your reply but its not working over corss domain.i am getting error nodetype on browser control

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var href= $("#xyz").attr("src", 
$(this).attr(".linklist_single a", 
$this.attr("target", "")));
});

</script>

Comment: @ManishJakhode – That code has absolutely nothing to do with what I said you should do in this answer.

Comment: simply i want to open all hyperlink of iframe child within iframe.

Comment: @ManishJakhode — Repeating your goal isn't going to change the answer.